# How can I pass javascript plain object thought ajax by POST method to the Spring mvn controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Here is my javascript:

```
var option = {};
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: URL,
  data: {options : option},
  dataType: "text"
});
```

here is my Spring MVC Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/item/{itemId}/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, )
public @ResponseBody
String saveItemAjax(@PathVariable("itemId") String itemId, @RequestParam("options") Object options, WebRequest request){
    LOGGER.debug("--------------->ajax called");
    return options.toString();
}
```

The result is an 400 error : bad request.
I think spring can not get a parameter as a javascript object.

How can I do that what I want then ?

Thanks

Comment: You should use JSON and JAXB mapping with Spring. to convert from javascript object to Java object

Comment: okay, then should I change the controller method ?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks great , except for the `@RequestParam("options") Object options`, the `Object` should be replace by your actual object

just make sure that you url map this pattern `/ajax/item/{itemId}/save`. 
Actually we dont see from your javascript the url value.

To help you more, I would need the value of `URL`, and `options` from your javascript file.

Comment: thank you, my URL should be okay. I just wonder if I have to create a class to bind the options data. my options is something simple like {"id":5,"name":"name"}

Comment: yes you have to, and you will use @RequestBody("options") instead of @RequestParam("options")